# onpopstate event not fired on window.history.forward()

Tags: javascript, event-listener

Im experimenting with the History API and ran into a problem which im not not able to resolve. After pushing a new state to the api im not able to get the popstateEvent fired on window.history.forward() (simulating the click on the forward button of the browser). With window.history.back() everything works as expected. Im wondering why this behaviour is happening. Is this intended?

```js
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
};

window.history.pushState({'state': 'test'}, '', '/testurl');

window.history.go(1);
window.history.back();
```

```js
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
};

window.history.pushState({'state': 'test'}, '', '/testurl');

window.history.go(1);
window.history.forward();
```

resources:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Tried Browsers:
Latest FireFox Quantum Beta
Latest Google Chrome Stable